# How was the prototype-robot for the Atari 2600 kept in the same position as the robot on screen?

Tags: robotics

QUESTION
How was the prototype-robot for the Atari 2600 kept in the same position as the robot on screen?

A photo and some details here :
https://www.retrothing.com/2008/12/atari-2600-cont.html

Was it just wheel odometry, I doubt anything else would have been considered, due to costs.

P.S. - It would be great if more prototypes from this company ( or companies ), and from any other companies could be documented, since they may have had impressive features, which were probably too expensive to manufacture .

UPDATE - This robot may have been more than a prototype, since it appears to have been FCC tested ( ? ), the results on the following webpage [The Atari Androbot Projects](http://www.atarimuseum.com/otherprojects/nonatari/androbot/andro-atari.html)

Comment: The article you cite also links to https://www.robotswanted.com/robotgallery/androbot/index.html where it states "First, you have to accumulate a number of points by playing the video game, then you must guide Androman around his 3-D landscape to intercept coded game pieces which activate a different type of game play". So it sounds like they weren't kept in sync and the physical robot read coded pieces somehow.

Comment: This robot may have been more than a prototype, since it appears to have been FCC tested ( ? ), the results on the following webpage  http://www.atarimuseum.com/otherprojects/nonatari/androbot/andro-atari.html